# JQuery Mobile Icon Pack Squished on IPhone

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

There seems to be [a current bug](https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack/issues/25) with JQueryMobile's FA Icon Pack where, if you roll a custom JQueryMobile theme then all of JQueryMobile's original icons [appear squished](http://games.contraterrene.com/screenshots/custom_theme.png) when you view it on an actual iPhone.

The suggested work around is to use FA Icon names instead of the original ones but this doesn't fix the problems with the listview and check box icons being squished.

Because of JQuery Mobile's popularity, I'm hoping someone has come across this and threw a quick fix together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually an incredibly easy fix for this, as I have experienced the same problem. Just make sure your custom theme rolled CSS file is injected into your HTML **BEFORE** your FA Icon pack CSS.